# Why is "BESbewy" appearing in my site spans?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, typekit

I noticed with firebug a span with "BESbewy" string inside it in the end of body with left and top with -999 and visibility hidden. The first thing a thought is that for some how I was hacked, but after a day searching I'm not so sure about this anymore, so I started to think that this is somehow related to Google Maps API v3.

Well, you can try searching for "BESbewy google maps" on Google and see how many results is shown, and looks to all be related to maps; by the way, this string is in developer.google.com too.

I'm trying to find some answer to this, but so far no success. Can someone help me to understand what is this BESbewy thing?

I notice that TinyMCE (which I'm not using at all) adds an span with "BESbswy" string inside it for some kind of font configuration. Well, since I don't use or have TinyMCE in my project and what I'm seeing is some kind of different (there is an 'e' in the place of 's') I'm kind of curious and confused (http://www.tomjn.com/153/typekit-besbswy/).

Comment: What problems are you having with it?

Comment: *"I was doing my things here, programming and such when I notice with firebug a span with "BESbewy " string inside it in the and of body with left and top with -999 and visibility hidden."* Notice it ***where***? In a page you've authored? Then yes, you've been hacked. On a page from someone else? Well, anything goes, they can do what they like. What **specific** issue are you having?

Comment: Erik Philips, the main problem is that I notice an strange html element on my page that I have never placed there. So I'm concerned with security here and want to know if this is some issue or is something from google maps api. Since I did search for it and can't find anything specific I'm not sure what it is. If you take a look at google you will see this string in many (6M+) sites including developer.google.com itself but can't find any reference to it.

Comment: T.J. Crowder, I notice it in my page HTML when doing something else with Firebug. It's an span element with BESbewy string inside it. It's the last element inside my index page body and seens to be only loaded if Google API is loaded.

Answer (score 10):

The Google Maps API seems to create one of these "BESbewy" `span` elements for each map instated on the page, with a style of `font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif` — by all appearances it's so Google Maps can calculate the size or existence of fonts.

It does not point to your site having been hacked, and if the existence bothers you, review how and when you're instating your Google Maps elements.

Comment: Extra clarity because downvotes: In our case, we were instating 20+ maps elements on pageload, so we got 20+ "BESbewy" elements.

Comment: See bottom of linked section: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#custom

Answer (score 2):

Among other issues due to a `page-ad` class applied on body, we've discovered that this `span` containing "BESbewy" was added by Adblock Plus on Chrome.

ABP adds this with a few other elements (including CSS rules).
Those CSS rules may affect the website when using unsuitable classes (independent of ABP lists).